# How would people interact in a world with cybernetically "shapeshifting" humans?

Tags: humans, social-norms, shapeshifters, cybernetics, cyborg

I'm curious what a world similar to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21260/whats-to-stop-shapeshifting-humans-from-changing-their-appearance-all-the-time) would be like if instead of genetic modifications, shapeshifting was done via cybernetic implants. This would not work by simply injecting some magical gene modifying virus from within the body, but by mechanical implants that can be electrically stimulated to change the user's appearance. For example, you could change the proportions of your face via inflating flexible implants in different parts of it.

While other options are permitted, I imagine this as being controlled via a brain interface. Modifications would take at most an hour, and could be carried out while awake (however some may be physically uncomfortable).

Answers can treat the society as close to modern day, however I imagine this tech becoming common in 2025-2035. I'd prefer answers to be based on the US, but if you have more experience with other countries that's fine too. The technology is out of the scope of this question, but in general the technology would be based more on simulating the look of modifications to the body, rather than electronically modifying the body itself. Assume that a set of implants would cost about \$600, but anywhere from \$50-1000 is fine if it changes your answer. Things that could be touched on:

- For things that could be changed almost instantly (like hair color depending on how it's implemented), would people that change it in the middle of conversations be frowned upon?
- How would prejudice against people based on how they look change if they could simply make themselves no longer look that way?
- Does this cause prejudice in it's own right?

There would be little-to-no implants for things that don't look "human." At least in the early stages of this technology, things like bright green skin would probably not be an option.

Comment: Why stop them?  What sort of stopping effort are you looking for? Social pressure?  Police action?  Legal rules?  Self Enlightenment?  What reasons do you have for stopping them?

Comment: Editing the question to clarify what I mean

Comment: Still not clear - who wants to stop them?  As it stands, it seems like they could do so and it wouldn't affect anyone in particular.

Comment: @jdunlop I hadn't edited the question yet.

Comment: Wrong title, oops. Haven't used StackExchange in a while...

Comment: Is this asking how the appearance would change, or simply its effect on society?

Comment: One method of doing this that makes physical sense though it would slow the maximum rate large changes could be made at would be to look to physics, specifically thermodynamics to serve as an absolute physical limit due to the waste heat involved in the process of restructuring matter. Organic tissues have a pretty limited tolerance for hyperthermia as such the added waste heat really can't afford to raise the body temperature by much more than 2 degrees Celcius (Around a 3 celcius rise in equilibrium body temperature gets into imminent danger of death territory).

Comment: It's effect on society, sorry. I thought a clarified that in the edit. Do you have any suggestions on how to make it clearer?

Comment: I feel that clarifying a bit more about your story's culture and society would help in narrowing down appropriate answers

Comment: @MttJocy This question isn't really about the technology itself. However, the way I imagine this, all of the implants would be simple enough that nothing would need cooling other than the neural interface. I could be wrong, but I don't believe a simple electrically-controlled pump creates much heat, if any.

Comment: @Bewilderer Is that good?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to World Building Snuggles. This question was originally basically a duplicate of the link, and your edit adds more problems. These are multiple, open ended questions. It would depend on the society you live in. Take Korea where Plastic surgery is widely accepted vs a more traditional country that believes in being yourself. The answer is it would basically depend. People aren't just going to all look like the same famous person (because they aren't that famous person and hence would likely be shamed identity theft).

Comment: @snuggles08 Fair enough but it is still worth considering the fact that chemically breaking down and building up kilograms of protein etc does involve the release and consumption of large amounts of chemical energy and thermodynamics limits the efficiency of doing this practically such that there would be waste heat while doing this. But reading your modified question I get that you are looking more into the realms of social norms etc, which really come down a lot more to how you build your setting, it's your culture you are creating after all.

Comment: @snuggles08 One other thing to consider here regarding social norms and such is that it's unlikely that every society will agree on these and even within societies subcultures that feel differently to the majority are very likely to exist so there is a lot of scope to explore different attitudes so it's not necessary to limit yourself to a single uniform point of view. Subcultures are also interesting as they can lead to conflict points with an ideologically opposed mainstream society and legal system.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  Please take a moment to [learn more about our culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) and take our [tour]. Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problems with quetions like this are they are not objective and tend to be very broad. Understand that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107#92110).

Comment: @JBH I've tried to make it less open ended while still keeping most of my points. I'm fine with you (or other people) making further edits, but I'll try to incorporate suggestions too.

Comment: The SE Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  I count 4 questions.  You'll likely always have people VTC this as too broad because predicting how everyone in the U.S. would react is impossible.  [Goths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goth_subculture) would react very differently compared to members of the [Christian right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_right).  Frankly, every reaction you can conceive of will occur in a nation of 300M people.  What exactly are you trying to learn?  I can tell you how I'd react if my 13yo daughter came home with this implant.

Comment: @JBH Thinking about it, this feels more like a writing prompt than a world-building question. I might have better luck on a forum for that... I'd still like this question to be clarified. Do you have any ideas on how to make it specific enough?

Comment: Indeed, storybuilding is off-topic here.  A specific example would be, "how might CNN report the development of a new technology, cybernetic shapeshifting?"  CNN's reporting behavior and philisophical/political inclinations are well defined and well known.  Thus, we could objectively explain how they would report such a technology.  However, the moment you ask how "the media" would report the tech, you're too broad again.  You can pretty much guarantee that FOX News would report the very opposite of CNN.

Answer (score 2):

Cybernetic implants are not cheap, and to have them on this large of a bodily scale, I suspect that only the rich would have access to this technology. Therefore, I could easily see shape-shifting becoming a status symbol among the upper class in your world. Therefore, it seems only natural that changing one's appearance at whim would be a somewhat common occurrence, if only to flaunt their wealth and social superiority. As a result, it would be common for people in lower social classes to try and emulate this cybernetic system as a way to make themselves seem richer than they actually are, such as how Chinese women have historically had their feet bound to emulate nobility. However, it also seems like this shape-shifting would bring with it a sort of social stigma, as it would permanently mark one as a member of the upper class, and may even upset religious institutions due to it defying the course of nature and the will of the God(s). I imagine that, in a few years after its introduction, it will either be so cheap as to be possessed by everyone and dismissed as a part of society, such as with cell phones, or it will fade into obscurity as simply another fad of the past.

Comment: This is a good answer! It brought up some points that I didn't consider while writing the question. I'm planning on changing my question to specify the device's availability, but this is still a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Humans to date**

Humans have a distinct and recognisable face to allow other individuals in their lives to recognise them. Humans were jewellery, clothing, and various forms of skin markings to increase their recognisability. They will even adapt items meant to help surviving the environment such as boots, gloves, armour, glasses, bows, hammers, houses, etc... to be apart of this recognisable identity.

All of our social structures require a way to identify an individual so that their reputation can be tracked. This includes attributing praise, blame, privilege, and duty. Without the ability to associate a reputation to someone you do not know if that person is trustworthy or dangerous to you. The only personally safe attitude would be to treat everyone as deadly raving killers. You won't get a lot of society in these circumstances.

Losing your identity now days is deeply problematic. It makes it hard to open a bank account when the bank believes you already owe them an absolute fortune. It makes it hard to get a job, when the police believe you are a criminal. It may even threaten your life as others come to claim what your reputation owes. Regaining or even keeping your identity requires a lot of hard work to re-establish your reputation and prevent others from trying to take/tarnish it.

For the most part having a reputation is so important to attaining privileges, that it even makes sense to wear some blame, and deal with some duties. Like being dressed down for being late (to keep the job), or taking out the trash (its not pleasant but the alternatives aren't better in the long run).

On the other hand there are times when being associated with a reputation is itself going to be a problem. Like being able to eat 3 meals a day in a poor neighbourhood, or being the boss in a room filled with discontent employees.

**Shapeshifters**

So this race of shapshifters will actively fight to have independently recognisable identities. That may not be their face, it could be their voice, or some other hard to replicate thing. Most of them will actively dissuade others from mimicking them on this/these identifying point/s. Those that copy exactly would be considered reprehensible because of identity theft. This would draw social pressure for one of them to change. It may not change in the originals favour though.

Some shapeshifters will try to be unidentifiable because they are avoiding punishment, or enjoying a life of non-socially endorsed activities. They might do this by adopting a similar appearance to others, or by adopting several distinct identities based on location/situation, or by never settling on a single look.

Whatever isn't involved in their identity will be changed day to day with the seasons and whim. But this won't be a lot. Most choices of shape will be interpreted by many as joining a specific group. If that shapeshifter does not personally identify with the group, they will have to bear the social misunderstanding, or change to something else.

Within a group individuals will want to be different. I could imagine some shapeshifters choosing fairy wings, others would associate those wings with that groups reputation. Yet each shapeshifter with fairy wings would have something different. It might be their hair, their height, whatever it is any reasonable observer could tell them apart.

The only time the shapeshifters might literally clone themselves is in forming together to express a single demand of society or a single service to society. Militaries, protest groups, police, and judicial figures leap to mind. Here personal reputation is not important, but professional/group reputation is key. When the group succeeds all of the members succeed, when the group fails all of the members fail. The strict group identity will disappear though the moment an individual will benefit/fail independent of the group. The more the individual benefit/failure anticipated due to the group the less resemblance to the group.